# Firefox Issue: Red border around Input text element on focus change

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, firefox

#### The goal is to render a form with multiple input fields.

> Expected result: All the input fields have consistent styling 
>   Actual result: `Email` field renders red border after entering data & changing focus.

This only happens with Firefox and not with Chrome.

[image: Screenshot from Firefox]

I have tried adding a solution from stackoverflow but that didn't change anything, I am using Bootstrap for the most part.

```css
.form-control:focus { box-shadow: none; }
```

Code from a the component is:

```js
<div className="col-6 cformrow">
 <label className="float-left">Email*</label>
  <input 
   className="form-control px-4 py-2"
   type={"email"}
   name={"PrimaryEmail"}
   pattern="[A-Za-z ]+"
   value={this.state.PrimaryEmail}
   onChange={this.getDetails}
  />

 <small className="form-text text-left text-danger p-absolute">  
  {this.state.PrimaryEmailerror}
 </small>
</div>
```

And the function that is called :

```js
getDetails = event => {
 if (event.target.name === "PrimaryEmail") {
  if (event.target.value.match(/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/)) {
   this.setState({ [event.target.name + "error"]: "" });
  } else {
   this.setState({ PrimaryEmailerror: "Please enter a valid email" });
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Try this: `input:focus { outline-width: 0;}`  Or in general, to affect all basic form elements: `input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus,button:focus { outline: none;}`

Comment: Could there be a problem with your pattern? It seems like you only accept upper and lowercase letters with ```pattern="[A-Za-z ]+"```, so it makes sense that the error border gets triggered when entering a "valid" Email.

Comment: see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#Basic_validation about your pattern

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, Thank you very much I just tried that, and it seems to work now.

Comment: @Gh05d Thank You, you are right, I changed my pattern to 
`pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2, 4}$"` 
and the problem no longer exists for now.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
input:required {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

or :

```
::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with outline property, it worked for me.

```
outline: none;
```

Comment: This is not recommended as it will entirely disable the focus effect added on elements for users who are using keyboard to navigate the site.

Answer (score 0):

You see the red outline correctly. Browser is showing you that what you typed in the field is not passing the test of the `pattern`, not what was expected. Review of your `pattern` attribute and fix it so you can type in all kinds of email addresses into the field and get positive verification by the browser.

Fix this pattern to match all kinds of email addresses
`pattern="[A-Za-z ]+"`

It's not recommended to disable `outline`. The best approach is to use already built in browser's form fields verification mechanisms. Remember `outline` is also used for keyboard navigation.